# Why is $\mathscr{A}_{\infty}=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \mathscr{A}_n$ never a $\sigma$-algebra?

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

> **Problem:** Let $(X, \mathscr{A})$ be a measurable space and $(\mathscr{A}_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a strictly increasing sequence of $\sigma$-algebras. Show that
>
> $$ \mathscr{A}_{\infty} := \bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \mathscr{A}_n $$
>
> is never a $\sigma$-algebra.

This is a problem of a book of *Rene Schilling*. He shows an answer of this problem on his homepage. However I don't understand the last part, Step 5. I don't know there always exists the smallest set $B_n$.

Here is [*his solutions*](http://www.motapa.de/measures_integrals_and_martingales/solutions-mims-2ed.pdf). This problem is **Problem 3.8. [pp.24-26]**

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please take time to read how to format your question using MathJax, [see this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#10164) for instance.

Comment: I also slightly changed the title and the formatting of the question. Hope this is to your liking!

Comment: Thank you for your editing.

Comment: $n\in \mathbb{N}\in \mathscr{A}_n$

Comment: To echo what user d.k.o mentioned, I think there is an implicit use of the well-ordering theorem.

Answer (score 1):

The problem reduces to the following.

> Let $\mathcal A$ be a $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb N$. For all $k\in\mathbb N$, there exists a minimal element (for the inclusion) $E_k$ of $\mathcal A$ containing $k$.

Indeed, define 
$$
I:=\left\{i\in\mathbb N\mid \exists A_i\in\mathcal A,k\in A_i,i\notin A_i\right\}.
$$
For each $i\in  I$, choose $A_i\in\mathcal A$ such that $k\in A_i$ and $i\notin A_i$. Define 
$$
E_k:= \bigcap_{i\in I}A_i.
$$
Then $E_k\in\mathcal A$ and $k\in E_k$. Let $B\in\mathcal A$ be such that $k\in B$. We have to check that $E_k\subset B$. Observe that $i\notin A_i$ hence 
$$
E_k= \bigcap_{i\in I}A_i\setminus \{i\}=\bigcap_{i\in I}A_i\cap \left(\mathbb N\setminus \{i\}\right)=E_k\setminus I.
$$
Let $j\in E_k=E_k\setminus I$. We know that for all $S\in\mathcal A$, we either have $k\notin S$ or $j\in S$. Apply this to $B$ to get that $k\notin B$ or $j\in B$. Since $k\in B$, the only possibility is that $j\in B$, which proves that $E_k\subset B$.

Comment: I think  the cardinality of σ-algebra is’t necessarily countable.So,I think “I” may be not well-defined.

Comment: Actually, a $\sigma$-algebra is either finite or uncountable but why would this be a problem in the definition of $I$?

Comment: I see there is no problem,Sorry,but I don’t understand why for all S∈A k is not an element of S or j∈S.

Comment: We know that $j$ is not an element of $I$: this means that for each element $S$  of $\mathcal A$, the assertion ($k\in S$ and $j\notin S$) is not true.

Comment: I have completely understood! Thank you for your answer.